# How to View My Postgres DB Schema from Command Line

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-south

So I have my Django app running and I just added South. I performed some migrations which worked fine locally, but I am seeing some database errors on my Heroku version. I'd like to view the current schema for my database both locally and on Heroku so I can compare and see exactly what is different. Is there an easy way to do this from the command line, or a better way to debug this?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about Heroku, but if you can shell into it Postgre has a command line tool called psql that will let you view the schema.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line you should be able to do `heroku pg:psql` to connect directly via PSQL to your database and from in there `\dt` will show you your tables and `\d <tablename>` will show you your table schema.

Answer (score 1):

locally django provides a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell) that will launch you into your db's shell.

`python manage.py dbshell`

Comment: Thanks - I tried this, but I don't see any commands for viewing the schema.

Comment: @user1697845 that can be done once your inside of postgres shell, i haven't used postgress in a while but i think it is `\dt`? use the `\h` command for help

Answer (score 0):

django also provides a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-appname-appname) that will display the sql for any app you have configure in your project, regardless of the database manager (SQLite, MySQL, etc) that you're using:

`python manage.py sqlall <app name>`

Try it! It could be usefull!